# Bring all windows of the same application to front on focus in Unity

Tags: unity, launcher, compiz

I am essentially trying to replicate the default window management behavior of macOS in Ubuntu since I've gotten so used to it over the years.

When a window of an application in macOS gets focus (either by clicking on it directly, clicking on it in the launcher, or selecting it with the app switcher `Alt+Tab`), **all** other windows of the same application are brought to the foreground. In Unity, however, only the focused window is brought to the front.

Is there a setting to achieve the desired behavior? Maybe in `ccsm`, `unity-tweak-tool`, `gconf-editor` , etc.?

I am aware that clicking on the application icon in the launcher twice will open up an overview of all open windows. This is not the behavior I want since I do not want any animation and I do not want the windows to change their position. I simply want them to move to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Unity worked like this in its very first version! However, this quickly changed to the current behaviour, where only the last active window is being raised on clicking the icon in the dock. *Unfortunately, [this appears to be hard coded and there is no setting to change that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127143/how-do-i-revert-the-alt-tab-behavior-so-that-switching-to-an-app-brings-to-the-f?rq=1).*

Gnome Shell, which is now the default desktop environment of Ubuntu, may suit you better in that respect.

- Pure Gnome Shell works exactly like that. Alt+tab brings all windows to the foreground. Clicking the icon in the dash, which in gnome shell is only visible from the overview, also raises all windows.
- Current Ubuntu versions now use Gnome Shell as the desktop environment. Accordingly, Alt+tab now works like you describe: it brings all window of the application to the foreground. Unfortunately, the Ubuntu dock does not work like that, nor can it be configured as such.
- An alternative options to have your dock icons permanently visible is to install the gnome extension [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/), which can be configured to raise all windows. However, this tends to look a lot like Windows...
- Yet another option to have a permanent dock that works like you are looking for is to add an external dock. Plank is a lightweight dock that out of the box acts like you prefer: it raises all windows of the application.